# Add df.to_html() to existing HTML page

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

Hello I am currently working on a project in python using web2py to obtain statistical data for NBA players. I am requesting a json from http://stats.nba.com. I am using [this code](http://www.danielforsyth.me/exploring_nba_data_in_python/) as a reference and will modify it once I understand it more clearly. I am creating a dataframe with all of the data. However, after I obtain the data and want to create an HTML table, I want to display it on an existing HTML page I have already created. Does anyone know how I would go about doing this? Here is my code for the function in which I use df.to_html():

```
def stats():
    with open ('applications/ballislife/static/team_players.json') as f:
        data=f.read()
        z=simplejson.dumps(data)
    #NBA Stats API using selected player ID
    #for x in teams:
    #    for y in teams[x]:
    #        find_stats(y,teams[x][y])
    find_stats('stephen curry','201939')
    find_stats('james harden','201935')
    #cols = ['name','avg_defender_distance','avg_dribbles','avg_shot_distance','avg_touch_time']
    cols = ['name', 'games', 'wins', 'losses', 'win_pct', 'minutes', 'fgm', 'fga', 'fg_pct', 'fg3m', 'fg3a', 'fg3_pct',
            'ftm', 'fta','ft_pct', 'pf', 'oreb', 'dreb', 'reb', 'ast', 'tov', 'stl', 'blk', 'pts', '+/-']
    #
    df = pd.DataFrame(players,columns = cols)
    print ('=========================')
    print df
    #return df.to_html()
    return dict(df=df)
```

If I simply return df.to_html(), it returns the table with none of the elements in the 'stats.html' file I have already created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was able to figure this out was by putting `{{=XML(df)}}` in the 'stats.html' file instead of simply `{{=df}}`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to turn `stats.html` into a template page in your [views](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views) with all of the HTML framework elements and links to your stylesheets, then inject the results of `df.to_html()` into it.